# Storing huge information in android app

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where I am going to display information about colleges like college name, address, courses available. Can anyone guide me how and where to store those information(assume that I want to store information of around 100 colleges).

Comment: Shared pref can hold that much without problem. But I would prefer SQLite db instead of XMLS. This might give you good insight : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database

Answer (score 2):

You should store your data in a Sqlite database, please check:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

Answer (score 1):

If it's only a few rows, you can use a simple XML file. If it has relationships and need some transaction functionality, SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to store data in an Android

1. SharedPreference
2. InternalStorage
3. ExternalStorage
4. SQLite Databases
5. Network Connection

Looking at your requirements I would suggest using SQLite, or store it on web somewhere and fetch through Network Connection or Store it internally in a file using InternalStorage.

More here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html